# Executing multiple instance of jetty runner at the same time

Tags: jetty

Is it possible to run the multiple instance of jetty runner at the same time.Like if the multiple user likes to start different war in the same server(all using jetty),the jetty has to execute all the requesting war at the same time.Any idea about implementing this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give it different ports and also set the JETTY_RUN variable differently for each of them otherwise they'll try to use the same pid file and won't be able to start.
I personally found that launching multiple instances creates a very high load on the server so I prefer just 1 with multiple contexts.

Comment: can you please explain your statement  "1 with multiple contexts".

Comment: @elvisanandkumar I was talking about having just 1 Jetty server instance serving multiple apps at different context paths. It's true that if you do that and you're behind a reverse proxy you will run into some trouble with relative links in websites, but it works well for rest apis.